# ng2 Autocomplete: showing 'Dot' when field is selected and focused

Tags: angular, autocomplete, ng2-bootstrap

I am using ng2-autocomplete in my reactive-FormControl with ng2-bootstrap. Everything is working fine except- a small grey dot (.) is coming before the text-box.

[Ng2-Bootstrap URL](https://github.com/ng2-ui/ng2-auto-complete)

Here is the Screen-shot -

[image]

I have tried many debugging but no luck. Please let me know if anyone has any idea.

Comment: Well we can't do anything if you do not show us any code ;)

Comment: Yes. Am already trying to reproduce it in Plunker.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a "dot". To me it looks more like some text that is being cut off.